# Javascript not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help!
I have a thumb image link swapping out on hover.
It works fine in Firefox and Safari but doesn't show on IE and Chrome.
I'm new to Javascript so please excuse me if I'm missing the obvious.
Thank you in advance.

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
 var fadingImage;
  $(".fade").hover(function(){
    fadingImage = $(this).find("img").eq(1);
    fadingImage.stop(true, true).fadeIn(250);
    }, function(){
    fadingImage.stop(true, true).fadeOut(250);
  });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<section class="brands_list">
    <div style="display:block; width:290; height:160;"" class="fade">
      <a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('siteurl')."/".$urlSlug."/".$brandSlug; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $brandLogo ?>" class="brand" alt="<?php echo $brandName ?>" width="290" height="160"/>
      <img src="<?php echo $brandImage ?>" class="brand" alt="<?php echo $brandName ?>" width="290" height="160"/>
      </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you show us the generated HTML, and not your PHP?

Comment: Javascript console of Chrome shows any error?

Answer (score 2):

Check your syntax - you have an extra `"` here on this line.

```
style="display:block; width:290; height:160;""
```

Other than this, your code appears to behave the same in IE7-10 as it does in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Maxthon, and Safari. This assumes your PHP doesn't produce malformed tags or anything.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ikotul/edit#javascript,html

The behavior I'm seeing in all browsers is the following.

```
+-----------------------+
|                       |
|                       |
|      Not Hovered      |
|                       |
|                       |
+-----------------------+
          ( mouse moves over left image )
+-----------------------+ +-----------------------+
|                       | |                       |
|                       | |                       |
|        Hovered        | |    Becomes Visible    |
|                       | |                       |
|                       | |                       |
+-----------------------+ +-----------------------+
```